# Execute command in other users' detached screen

Tags: gnu-screen

On my (ubuntu) server I have a gameserver running in a screen, owned by user_1. The gameserver has an interactive console to send commands to. Would it somehow be possible to execute a script as user_2 which sends input to user_1's detached screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
screen -r user_2 -X stuff "you_script.sh"
screen -r user_2 -X eval "stuff \015"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm still a bit lost tho.. I'm assuming it should be -r user_1, right? Since user_1 owns the screen. I'm also a bit confused about the 2 lines, are these just 2 examples or does "your_script.sh" gets assigned to 'stuff' which is then send wit the 'eval'? I just did a basic test as user_2: "screen -r user_1 -X echo test" which returns "No screen session found."

Comment: Oh, I read this question wrong I apologize. You can use `screen -r user_2 -X stuff "commands here"` to send the text `command here` from the current user to `user_2`. The second line in my answer sends a newline.